# Passing Ruby's thread hash/context to another thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to a pass a Thread's context (basically `Thread.current` hash) to another thread.

I am doing a `Thread.new` from an existing thread and I want this new thread to have access to the current (i.e calling thread's) hash.

This is inside ruby MRI 1.9.3/Rails 3.2.8 environment.

Comment: Sawa answer is correct but just want to the reason of doing it do you want to access some variable inside new thread that belongs to  other thread like the one explain by sawa or you want something else

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass fiber local values then go with:

```
Thread.current[:foo] = 'bar'
Thread.new(Thread.current) do |parent_context|
  parent_context.keys.each do |k|
    Thread.current[k] = parent_context[k]
  end

  puts Thread.current[:foo]
end.join
```

But with thread local values you should use [Thread#thread_variable_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Thread.html#method-i-thread_variable_set) and [Thread#thread_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Thread.html#method-i-thread_variable_get):

```
Thread.current.thread_variable_set(:foo, 'bar')
Thread.new((Thread.current)) do |parent_context|
  puts parent_context.thread_variable_get(:foo)
end.join
```

[Check out docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Thread.html#method-i-thread_variable_get) for a difference between fiber and thread local values

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.new do
  $binding = binding
  msg = "Message from another thread"
end.join

Thread.new($binding){|b| eval("p msg", b)}.join
# => "Message from another thread"
```

Comment: Although this doesn't seem to work for Thread.current which is what I think the answer was about

Comment: Yea this doesnt work for Thread.current, so basically not what I was looking for :(